res.cookie with Cors NodeJS ( No HTTP ok Status )
So i am in middle of making a e commerce react app, and i deployed it on vercel to test it out as well as showcase it on my cv. However, i am unable to get my protected routes to work. My public route is working and fetches items smoothly but my post request to /api/auth/login gets blocked by cors

/login:1  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://react-js-e-commerce-store-server.vercel.app/api/auth/login' from origin 'https://react-js-e-commerce-store-client.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

const loginUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    console.log(email,password)
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
      return res.status(401).send('Invalid email or password!');
    }
    const userInfo = {userID: user.userID, role: user.role}
    const token = generateJWT(userInfo);
    const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken(userInfo);
    user.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    await user.save();
    res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, // expires in 3 days
      secure: true, // Ensures the cookie is sent over HTTPS only
      httpOnly: false, // Prevents client-side JS from accessing the cookie
      sameSite: 'none' // Allows cross-site cookie sharing
    });
    return res.status(201).send({message:"Loggedin Successfuly", user:userInfo, token:token});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.status(500).send('Error logging in user!');
  }
};

changing the attributes of res.cookie but this still doesnt work.
{
  "src": "/api/(.*)",
    "headers":{
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://react-js-e-commerce-store-client.vercel.app",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    },
  "dest": "/auth.routes.js"
},

Added these header lines to vercel.json and the error changes to no HTTP ok status. ??

login:1  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://react-js-e-commerce-store-server.vercel.app/api/auth/login' from origin 'https://react-js-e-commerce-store-client.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.


Please try install cors package and then in the server code set the cors headers if not already done. Alternatively if you don't want to install additional package try set the cors header manually in server side code.

I already have cors package installed. I have seen multiple people saying install cors package but i dont get it, i already have it?

After install have you added cors configuration as well?

{
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
}
above is my package.json, clearly shows I have cors package installed
app.use(
cors({
origin: allowedOrigins,
allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
credentials:true
})
);
app.options('*', cors());
above is part of my app.js, the settings I'm using for cors

app.use(cors({ origin: 'https://react-js-e-commerce-store-client.vercel.app' /* Replace with your client's origin */ })); Alternatively try to use https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ as a proxy in your client app.
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://react-js-e-commerce-store-server.vercel.app/api/auth/login' But this second option is a workaround

so you are telling me to replace allowedOrigins var with my client side URL instead?. I mean, my public route /users/products which requires no cookie or auth works as intended but these don't.
https://github.com/humayunraza1/ReactJS-E-commerce-Store
here the git repo, have a look at codes and see if you can find something that should be changed

FIXED:
The problem was due to vercel. Hosted the server on aws-eleasticbeanstalk and everything worked smoothly.
